# How can I easily select the word my cursor is currently inside?

Tags: macos, keyboard

I'm looking to be able to select the current word my text cursor is inside on OSX (10.7.3).

For people who have used vim before, I want to be able to do a similar thing to the 'ci_' command, where '_' can be 'w', '(', '[', etc. to specify deleting the word or contents of a parens/bracket and enter insert mode.

The best way I've figured to do this is Option+Left then Shift+Option+Right to first navigate to the left end of the word, then select to its right end.
Is there a way I can create a macro to do both of these at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been covered in a [screencast on the Ask Different Blog](http://apple.blogoverflow.com/2012/03/keyboard-ninja-working-with-text-screencast/). I encourage you to watch the video, but I'll summarize here.

First, create a little AppleScript that presses the two keyboard shortcuts. Open AppleScript Editor (in /Applications/Utilities) and paste this in:

```
tell application "System Events"
    key code 123 using option down
    key code 124 using {shift down, option down}
end tell
```

Save that as a script in ~/Library/Scripts (create the folder if it doesn't already exist).

Now, install the app [FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/). It's free for up to 10 scripts.
Open the FastScripts preferences, find your Select Word script, and assign a keyboard shortcut to it.

Now you can press your chosen shortcut in any app and the current word will be selected.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to create ~/Library/KeyBindings/ and save a property list like this as DefaultKeyBinding.dict:

```
{
    "~w" = selectWord:; // option-w
}
```

The custom keybindings don't work in some cross-platform applications (or currently Xcode), but they don't have any perceivable delays like AppleScripts or Keyboard Maesto macros.

For more information, see [hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/Site/Cocoa Text System.html](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/Site/Cocoa%20Text%20System.html), [lri.me/keybindings](http://lri.me/keybindings), and [brettterpstra.com/tag/keybindings](http://brettterpstra.com/tag/keybindings).

Comment: Unfortunately Xcode is where I'd most prefer to use these bindings. But the delay-free aspect is interesting! Thanks (I'd up vote, but my low rep on this exchange won't allow me)